# C# Multiple if condition better way to code

Tags: c#, if-statement, .net-6.0

I have multiple if conditions, that doesn't look good, because each condition has different message so it is difficult to make it generic, is there a better way to enhance it so that looks cleaner,

```
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Code))
            {
                return BadRequest("Code is required.");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
            {
                return BadRequest("Id is required.");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            {
                return BadRequest("Name is required.");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(holding))
            {
                return BadRequest("Holding is required.");
            }
```

Comment: How do you judge "better"?

Comment: Are you looking for the data annotation, [RequiredAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: The only thing i would change is to use $"{nameof(Code)} is required" so you can change the name of the property and the Message will be still correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in a dictionary and validate all, then you can also return all invalid:

```
var nameValues = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    { { nameof(Code), Code }, { nameof(Id), Id }, { nameof(Name), Name }, { nameof(holding), holding }};

List<string> emptyFieldList = nameValues
    .Where(kv => string.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value))
    .Select(kv => kv.Key)
    .ToList();

if(emptyFieldList.Any())
{
    string emptyFields = string.Join(" and ", emptyFieldList);
    return BadRequest($"{emptyFields} is required."); // TODO: change "is" to "are" if emptyFieldList.Count > 1
}
```

If you only want to return the first invalid as in your code:

```
if(emptyFieldList.Any())
{
    return BadRequest($"{emptyFieldList.First()} is required.");
}
```